# insert from one table to another table use procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, insert, cursor

I want to insert from one table to other with some edits in values. source table has 20,000,000 records and insert and commit them impossible . so i write a procedure to commit each 1000 insert in a loop. but it does not work. what is the problem?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CONVERT_INTO_K2 IS

  batch_size number;
   row_num number;

  CURSOR trans IS

    select rownum,KWP_Trns_Utils.Get_Acnt_From_TRACNTID(t.TRPAN),
           t.TRPRRN, t.TRSIDE,t.switchcode,t.kcb_switchcode,
           t.TERMID, t.TRTERMID,t.TRPOSCCOD,t.TRCAID,
           t.TRMTI,t.TRPRCOD,t.TR87RSPCOD,t.TRMSGRSN,
           t.TRREVFLG,t.TRSETTMD,t.TRCURCOD,t.TRAMNT,
           t.TRORGAMNT,t.TRCHBLCUR,t.TRFEEAMNT,t.TRCHBLAMNT,
           t.TRFRWIIC,t.TRACQIIC,t.TRRECIIC,t.PTRTRCNO,
           t.BTRRN, t.TRTRACEDT, t.TRRSPDT, t.TRLDATE,
           t.TRLTIME, t.BAID, t.BADATE,t.TRACNTID1,
           KWP_Trns_Utils.Get_Acnt_From_TRACNTID(t.TRACNTID2),
           t.ATJHNO,t.ATJHDAT, t.TRORGDTELM,t.TRADDATA,
           KWP_Trns_Utils.Get_Acnt_From_TRACNTID(t.TRACNTID2),
           Trn_ID.Nextval, Trn_diag.Nextval,
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
      from P912.KCTRNS t

     where t.trprcod != 47
       and rownum < 200;

BEGIN

  batch_size := 0;
   row_num:=0;
  FOR rec IN trans LOOP
    batch_size := batch_size + 1;
     row_num := row_num + 1;

    if  MOD( row_num, 1000 ) != 0 then
       insert into P912.KCTRNS2
      (srcpan,rfrnnum, trnsid,swchcod, prswchcod,intrtrmid,
       xtrntrmid,trmcod, aptrid,msgtypidnt,trntyp,
       rspcod, msqrsn,rvrsflg,sttlsts,currcod,
       amt,origamt,crdhldrcurrcod,feeamt,
       crdhldrdiscamt, isurcrdinstid,acqrcrdinstid,
       rcvrcrdinstid,trcnum,intrrfrnnum,
       rcvdt,rspdt, prrcvdtsctn,prrcvtmsctn,
       btchid, btchiopendt,firsacctnum,
       scndacctnum,docnum,docdt, origdtelmt,
       dditdat,dstpan, id, diag, mngcod,
       funccod, sttlcod,trnres, custno,
       crdlesstrcno,accttyp1,accttyp2,chnltyp)

    Values
      (KWP_Trns_Utils.Get_Acnt_From_TRACNTID(t.TRPAN),
           t.TRPRRN, t.TRSIDE,t.switchcode,t.kcb_switchcode,
           t.TERMID, t.TRTERMID,t.TRPOSCCOD,t.TRCAID,
           t.TRMTI,t.TRPRCOD,t.TR87RSPCOD,t.TRMSGRSN,
           t.TRREVFLG,t.TRSETTMD,t.TRCURCOD,t.TRAMNT,
           t.TRORGAMNT,t.TRCHBLCUR,t.TRFEEAMNT,t.TRCHBLAMNT,
           t.TRFRWIIC,t.TRACQIIC,t.TRRECIIC,t.PTRTRCNO,
           t.BTRRN, t.TRTRACEDT, t.TRRSPDT, t.TRLDATE,
           t.TRLTIME, t.BAID, t.BADATE,t.TRACNTID1,
           KWP_Trns_Utils.Get_Acnt_From_TRACNTID(t.TRACNTID2),
           t.ATJHNO,t.ATJHDAT, t.TRORGDTELM,t.TRADDATA,
           KWP_Trns_Utils.Get_Acnt_From_TRACNTID(t.TRACNTID2),
           Trn_ID.Nextval, Trn_diag.Nextval,
           1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);



  else 

    insert into P912.KCTRNS2
      (srcpan,rfrnnum, trnsid,swchcod, prswchcod,intrtrmid,
       xtrntrmid,trmcod, aptrid,msgtypidnt,trntyp,
       rspcod, msqrsn,rvrsflg,sttlsts,currcod,
       amt,origamt,crdhldrcurrcod,feeamt,
       crdhldrdiscamt, isurcrdinstid,acqrcrdinstid,
       rcvrcrdinstid,trcnum,intrrfrnnum,
       rcvdt,rspdt, prrcvdtsctn,prrcvtmsctn,
       btchid, btchiopendt,firsacctnum,
       scndacctnum,docnum,docdt, origdtelmt,
       dditdat,dstpan, id, diag, mngcod,
       funccod, sttlcod,trnres, custno,
       crdlesstrcno,accttyp1,accttyp2,chnltyp)

    Values
      (KWP_Trns_Utils.Get_Acnt_From_TRACNTID(t.TRPAN),
           t.TRPRRN, t.TRSIDE,t.switchcode,t.kcb_switchcode,
           t.TERMID, t.TRTERMID,t.TRPOSCCOD,t.TRCAID,
           t.TRMTI,t.TRPRCOD,t.TR87RSPCOD,t.TRMSGRSN,
           t.TRREVFLG,t.TRSETTMD,t.TRCURCOD,t.TRAMNT,
           t.TRORGAMNT,t.TRCHBLCUR,t.TRFEEAMNT,t.TRCHBLAMNT,
           t.TRFRWIIC,t.TRACQIIC,t.TRRECIIC,t.PTRTRCNO,
           t.BTRRN, t.TRTRACEDT, t.TRRSPDT, t.TRLDATE,
           t.TRLTIME, t.BAID, t.BADATE,t.TRACNTID1,
           KWP_Trns_Utils.Get_Acnt_From_TRACNTID(t.TRACNTID2),
           t.ATJHNO,t.ATJHDAT, t.TRORGDTELM,t.TRADDATA,
           KWP_Trns_Utils.Get_Acnt_From_TRACNTID(t.TRACNTID2),
           Trn_ID.Nextval, Trn_diag.Nextval,
           1, 1, sttl_cod.Nextval, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
           end if;


    IF batch_size = 10 THEN
      begin
        COMMIT;
      end;
      batch_size := 0;
    end if;

  END loop;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    ROLLBACK;

END CONVERT_INTO_K2;
```

Comment: A better description of how “it does not work” would help everybody. Can you make a copy of what happens when you execute this procedure in `plsql`?

Comment: 20,000,000 rows isn't really all that much. How many indexes exist on the target table, and can you drop them temporarily while the data is being copied? Plus - your cursor is limiting you to the first 200 rows returned by the query (`rownum < 200`). ???

Comment: @BobJarvis limit <200 is just for test , 17 indexes , 90% of them are composite index of 3,4 columns . No the indexes can not be drop in source

Comment: Well, those indexes are why the data copy is slow. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The `Values` expression references `t` instead of `rec` the actual name of the cursor record. Try changing those `t` (only those in the `Values` expression, *not* those in the `select`) into `rec`.

Also make an alias for `KWP_Trns_Utils.Get_Acnt_From_TRACNTID(t.TRPAN)` it will be easier. Otherwise you will have to double quote (`"`) and upper case the column name in the `Values` clause.

Finally and **most importantly** at first sight your need would be better served by using a `insert into … from (select …)` syntax. Does this not work?

Failling that, a more robust approach would be to add some form of state column to your source (`PSAM952.KCTRNS`) table that would indicate that the entry has already been inserted into the destination (`PSAM961.KCTRNS2`) table. Say `0` for the default value, `1` meaning it will be part of next batch, and `2` to say it has been copied.

Comment: Using a set based approach, with direct path and perhaps some parallelism would be a much better and much faster approach. 20 million rows is not that much.

Comment: @BobC please explain more . what is your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are doing a mod() of row_num to provide some conditional logic. But you do not have an order-by on you cursor, so the row to which the row_num is applied is not deterministic. Of course one you apply and order-by, then you need to rethink rownum, since that is applied prior to an order-by. So you really need to re-evaluate the logic of what you are trying to do.

Having said that, you can perform conditional logic during the insert as shown below.

```
insert /*+ APPEND */ into PSAM961.KCTRNS2
select KWP_Trns_Utils.Get_Acnt_From_TRACNTID(t.TRPAN)
      , t.TRPRRN
      ,etc
      ...
      case when xxx=0 then stt1_cod.nextval else 0 end
      ,1
      ,1
      ,etc 
from PSAM952.KCTRNS t
     where t.trprcod != 47
       and rownum < 200;
```